# Cakephp : Login Admin with AuthComponent

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have one table whose name is admins. Its contains username and password fields. My sales user use admins table for the sales login. I want to login sales using AuthComponent. I have write code for this as below.

**AppController**

```
public $components = [ 
        'Auth' => [ 
                'loginAction' => [ 
                        'controller' => '',
                        'action' => 'login' 
                ],
                'logoutRedirect' => [ 
                        'controller' => '',
                        'action' => 'login' 
                ],
                'loginRedirect' => [ 
                        'controller' => '',
                        'action' => 'deshboard' 
                ],
                'className' => 'MyAuth'
        ]]

public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = [
                    'Form' => ['userModel' => 'admin', "fields" => ["username" => "username", 
                                                                                "password" => "password"]
                    ]];
}
```

**SalesController**

```
function login() {
    $post = $this->request->data('Admin');

    if ($this->request->is('post') && !empty($post)) {

        //var_dump($this->Auth->login());exit;
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->Auth->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }

        // perform login throttling (failure and block) if Sales or Admin portal
        // set an appropriate failure message
    }
}
```

When I have print the return value of auth->login() function. Its always return false.

I have search a lots for this issue but I am unable to find any proper answer.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: What's in MyAuthComponent class?

Comment: I have created on Class for the Authentication... But it is not necessary for this case

Comment: So why don't you delete the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find the solution for my above issue.

This issue is because of passwordHaser. I use difference password in the add or update password so we have to define the passwordHaser in the component configuration, if we don’t use simple encription.

```
 'Auth' => [
        'className'      => 'MyAuth',
        'authenticate'   => [
            'Form' => [
                'userModel' => 'Admin',
                'fields'    => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Simple'
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],
```